# How to get the amount of jobbers per area?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the amount of jobbers (employees) per area (work) but i don't know how to do it. I tried doing this

```
select NOMBRE_ORDEN_TRABAJO,
    id_usuario as Jobber_count
from tareas 
group by NOMBRE_ORDEN_TRABAJO;
```

I get this

[image]

I think i should use the sentence COUNT.

This is my bd (in excel) where you can see i have an user id (ID USUARIO) and nombre orden trabajo (aerea/work name)... I'd like to count every jobber/employer per aera/work..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need a `COUNT` in there.

Try...

```
select NOMBRE_ORDEN_TRABAJO,
    COUNT(id_usuario) as Jobber_count
from tareas 
group by NOMBRE_ORDEN_TRABAJO;
```

This will give you the number of `id_usuario` per `NOMBRE_ORDEN_TRABAJO`

If you are concerned there may be duplicates change to `COUNT(DISTINCT id_usuario)`